# How to make multiple requests with ruby oauth?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, oauth

I was able to get an access token working with oauth, but the end point limits the maximum records per request to 100.

I need to get more than that, and am wondering if there is a simple/common way to do this?

I'd like to keep making requests until I get all the records. For example:

```
@products = JSON.parse(@access_token.get("/api/rest/products?page=#{@n}&limit=100").body)
```

I may need 10,000+ of the products. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming @products is an array of products you should be able to do this

```
@products = []

(1..100).each do |page|
  @products << JSON.parse(@access_token.get("/api/rest/products?page=#{page}&limit=100").body)
end
```

If you don't know exactly how many pages or products there are, unless the api provide you that, you can do something like this to stop fetching when there are no more products.

```
@products = []

# Assuming you never want more then 10.000
(1..100).each do |page|
  new_products = JSON.parse(@access_token.get("/api/rest/products?page=#{page}&limit=100").body)
  @products << new_products
  break if new_products.size < 100
end
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't clarify before, the but qty of products is variable.

Comment: Okay, cool thanks. I pretty much was heading this way, but wasn't sure if the oauth object had some built-in methods to make multiple requests. Thanks for the help.